# SVG zoom issue in IE10 (expand more than SVG size)

Tags: svg, maps, d3.js, internet-explorer-10

Making map with d3.js with zoom option like here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541. While testing in IE10 found that map expands to whole page when it is zoomed. I tried to add extra `<div>`, but it didn't work. Any idea how to fix this?

Now I have such code:

```
var mapWidth = 500,
mapHeight = 260;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
.scale(550)
.translate([mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var svgDiv = d3.select("body").append("div")
.attr("width", mapWidth)
.attr("height", mapHeight)
.attr("class", "svgDiv");

var svgMap = svgDiv.append("svg")
.attr("width", mapWidth)
.attr("height", mapHeight);

var svgBack = svgMap.append("rect")
.attr("width", mapWidth)
.attr("height", mapHeight)
.attr("pointer-events", "all")
.style("fill", "none")
.on("click", reset);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176500/d3-objects-do-not-render-within-svg-bounds-on-ie10

Comment: Thx it works now, with `.attr("overflow", "hidden")`. Any explanation why IE act so weird in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding .attr("overflow", "hidden") to SVG solve issue and no need in using `<div>`.

Working code looks so:

```
var mapWidth = 500,
mapHeight = 260;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
.scale(550)
.translate([mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var svgMap = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("overflow", "hidden")
.attr("width", mapWidth)
.attr("height", mapHeight);

var svgBack = svgMap.append("rect")
.attr("width", mapWidth)
.attr("height", mapHeight)
.attr("pointer-events", "all")
.style("fill", "none")
.on("click", reset);
```