# D3 Zoomable Circle Packing in IE11 is expanding beyond the SVG boundary

Tags: d3.js, svg, internet-explorer-11, circle-pack

Try Mike's original sample in raw mode in IE11:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/7607535/

[image]

The expanded circle is bleeding out of the SVG area.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this browser specific issue for IE 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using overflow hidden on svg.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that fixes the problem. It's funny when I search for the answer but found nothing, however when I submitted the question a related question showed up in "Related topic". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294417/svg-zoom-issue-in-ie10-expand-more-than-svg-size